# Predicting when and where a conflict is most likely to take place (glm/ train test set error)

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, train

I am having difficulty analysing this dataset (I am new to statistics and R). I am trying to model when a conflict is most likely to take place (before, during or after deforestation), and at what distance to this it will occur using this data set (example from excel)[image: 1] (I only have 53 points).

I have been pointed in the direction of a glm and have managed some simple statistics (assessed normality of residuals and homogeneity of variances- not normal/ performed a Kruskal Wallace to see if distance from deforestation is different before, during & after, and if it differs depending on the number of years since murder) but cannot go further in creating a train/test set. I think this is because for "During" the distance and number of years is always 0 (?).

```
> set.seed(1234)
> create_train_test <- function(data, size=0.8, train=TRUE){n_row=nrow(data) total_row=size*n_row train_sample <- 1:total_row if(train==TRUE){return(data[train_sample, ]) }else{return(data[-train_sample, ])}}
> data_train <- create_train_test (data,0.8, train=TRUE)
> data_test <- create_train_test(data,0.8,train=FALSE)
Error in data[-train_sample,]: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Any direction forward is appreciated, I may just be on the complete wrong track! Thanks :)

Comment: Tests are for evaluating hypotheses, not for estimation or exploration.  Why not begin with a map?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have already created a map on Arc which is where I got the distances from. I suppose my hypothesis is that there is a correlation between the distance from deforestation and likelihood of the event occurring?

Comment: The next step, then, is to view a scatterplot of deforestation and distance and contemplate ways to smooth it or estimate any apparent underlying pattern.

Comment: You are probably going to need to give us more information by editing your original question. The scatterplot might be a first step.